# How do I get Jekyll to copy favicons from a subdirectory to root when publishing?

Tags: jekyll, favicon

I use realfavicongenerator.net to generate `favicon.ico` and all the other files required nowadays. This is [a lot of files](https://realfavicongenerator.net/faq#why_so_many_files) (over 10) and as they [recommend](https://realfavicongenerator.net/faq#why_icons_in_root), I keep them in the site root. This looks quite messy and makes it slower to see important stuff such as my configuration files amongst them.

What I'd like to do is to keep them all in a `_favicon` subfolder, but have a Jekyll configuration option that copies the contents of the subfolder to the root of `_site` when publishing. Is there an option that'll do this?

Comment: RealFaviconGenerator's author speaking. If you use this technique, keep in mind to select "root" as the icons location when generating your icons. This has an impact on the generated HTML and also some of the generated files. Don't assume you can search&replace "/path/to/icons" by "/" along with the copy you are trying to achieve with Jekyll.

Comment: Yes, I'd be generating them for 'root'. I'd just be storing them in a subfolder in the Jekyll source files, but the published site will have them in root. Assuming someone answers with a way to get Jekyll to do this.

Comment: Alright, at least everything else is ready. Now you just need a Jekyll expert to answer :)

Answer (score 6):

After encountering the same problem. I did some digging around and finally decided to write a ruby plugin for this. It would be a better solution that storing some of your files in an icon folder but having to keep other files like `browserconfig.xml` and `favicon.ico` in the root because of Yandix. What this will give you is a way to keep all the files in one place and copy them to the `_site` folder on build. <-- this is what was asked for. Not some ""hacky"" solution.

1. Make a folder in root called _plugins.
   Jekyll automatically uses plugins from this folder during build. Name the file something like copy-my-files.rb
   So: `./_plugins/copy-my-files.rb`

ruby plugin code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'fileutils'

module Jekyll
  Jekyll::Hooks.register :site, :post_write do |post|
    Dir.glob('_favicon/*.*') do |file|
      sourcePath = file
      outputPath = File.join('_site', File.basename(file) )
      FileUtils.cp(sourcePath, outputPath)
    end
  end
end
```

What this will do is every time the site gets built it will copy all the files from `_favicon` into the `_site` folder.

2. Include the generated links in `_includes/head.html`
   or
   Write a file that contains all the links called `favicons.html`

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/apple-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/apple-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/apple-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/apple-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/apple-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/apple-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/apple-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="/android-icon-192x192.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="/favicon-96x96.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/ms-icon-144x144.png">
<meta nam

e="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

3. If you made a separate file called `favicons.html` include it in your head with this: `{% include favicons.html %}`

{% include favicons.html %}

So this will work because all of the files in `_favicon` fill get copied. The site.wbmanifest, manifest.json and all the png icons and what not.

Like another post has said you can break this out into its own html partial include `{% include favicons.html %}` and you would then link `includes/favicons.html` in your header.html file.

Comment: This is awesome, jekyll should have something like this built into the _config.yml file.

Comment: This did not work for me. No files were copied. also no errors

Answer (score 1):

I use a similar favicon generator, but locate the generated files in a subfolder to keep things *clean*, then I load them with a partial `{% include favicons.html %}` and in `includes/favicons.html`:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="57x57" href="{{ 'assets/favicons/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png' | absolute_url }}" />
....
```

Real question is, do they really need to be on the root folder? I don't think so. These are the reasons they gave to put them at root and how to deal with them:

- > Internet Explorer looks for favicon.ico at the root of the web site.
  >   Granted: this is because we ask you to not declare favicon.ico.

Then you just need to keep **one favicon** at root, and that is `favicon.ico`, all the rest can be in a subdirectory.

- > iOS devices look for files such as apple-touch-icon-144x144.png at the
  >   root of the web site, as described by Apple. This issue can be
  >   mitigated by declaring the icons in the HTML code (this is necessary
  >   for Android anyway), but following Apple conventions is probably the
  >   best move.

Explicitely declaring all favicons paths works, the ones that would be loaded in the partial file, as stated by the recommended Apple's [page](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html):

> To specify an icon for a single webpage or replace the website icon
>   with a webpage-specific icon, add a link element to the webpage, as
>   in:

- > By default, Internet Explorer 11 looks for browserconfig.xml at the
  >   root of the web site.

Just keep `browserconfig.xml` at root and refer to favicons inside it to the proper path.

- > Several services, such as Yandex, look for favicon.ico in the root
  >   directory.

Same as first reason, just keep `favicon.ico` at root.

---

If you still want them at root, use wrappers for main Jekyll commands: `build` and `serve` instead of using them directly:

For example for build:

```
mkdir _finalsite
cp -r * _finalsite/
cp _favicons/* _finalsite/  
jekyll build -s _finalsite
```

Comment: Yeah, the latter is kind of what my co-workers were suggesting. Wrapping the Jekyll commands in a shell script. I was hoping a Jekyll command or plugin for this existed though. Thanks!